# Some confusion on an example of Hungerford's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here is an example on Hungerford's *Algebra*, page 31.
[image]

But I don't think this argument is correct, according to the definition of homomorphism, $g(xy)=g(x)g(y)~x,y\in \mathbf{Z}_m$ that means the congruence equation $$ k(xy\bmod{m}) \equiv (kx)(ky)\pmod{km}$$but the preceding equation may not be true for an arbitrary positive integer $k$.

Did I have any misunderstanding on this example?

Comment: The operation is addition, not multiplication.

Comment: Just to emphasize:  $\mathbb Z_m$ is not even a group under multiplication; $0$ has no inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Z_m$ is not always a group under  multiplication. So when he is referring to the map

$g: Z_m \to Z_{mk} $ 
$x \mapsto kx$

then $g(x+y) = k(x+y)=kx+ky=g(x)+g(y)$

thus it's a homomorphism. As to why is injectiv just note, that the image has the same number of elements as $Z_m$ has.